# Priority in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

When I use `ORDER BY` clause to sort table by one simple column, it ok. But also I know there is an opportunity to mix columns ins `ORDER BY` clause to sort. But how does it works? How postgres set priorities? (Perhaps, I do not know something, correct me please if I am wrong in some way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The columns or expressions in an order by specify the ordering of the rows in the result set.

If you have multiple columns or expressions (called *keys*), the first key is used to sort the data.  The second key is only used when there is a tie for the first key.  Similarly, the third key is only used when there is a tie for the first two keys.

So, the result is a lot like a telephone book order by `(lastname, firstname)`.  The `firstname` is only used when there are multiple entries for the same `lastname`.

Answer (score 1):

The priority is in order of columns listed after `order by`, here's an example:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table_name order by col1, col3, col2

|col1|col2|col3|
|   1|   1|   1|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   2|   1|   1|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   2|   1|   2|
|   2|   2|   2|
```

Comment: What does this answer mean? What does that invalid syntax mean?

Comment: @jarlh thank you for the comment, I am sorry for the late response